# Why can't I control Firefox using Selenium/Javascript on Ubuntu 22.04, when I can with Python?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, ubuntu-22.04

I have a python script to control firefox using selenium, and it works fine:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://dev.to")
 
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "crayons-header--search-input").send_keys("Selenium")
```

I'm trying to do the same thing using javascript, and getting an error that "binary is not a Firefox executable"

Here is the current javascript:

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

(async function example() {
  // Define the path to the Firefox binary
  // const firefoxOptions = new firefox.Options().setBinary('/usr/bin/firefox');
  const firefoxOptions = new firefox.Options().setBinary('/real_path_here/firefox/firefox');

  // Create a new WebDriver instance with Firefox
  const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').setFirefoxOptions(firefoxOptions).build();

  try {
    // Navigate to the website
    await driver.get('https://dev.to');

    const searchInput = await driver.findElement(By.className('crayons-header--search-input'));
    await searchInput.sendKeys('Selenium', Key.RETURN);
    await driver.wait(until.titleIs('Search Results - DEV Community'), 10000);

  } finally {
    await driver.quit();
  }
})();
```

When I run this using node I get this error message:

```
Selenium Manager binary found at /real_path_here/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/bin/linux/selenium-manager
Driver path: /snap/bin/geckodriver
Browser path: /home/sumofchemicals/.cache/selenium/firefox/linux64/118.0.1/firefox
/real_path_here/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:524
    let err = new ctor(data.message)
              ^

InvalidArgumentError: binary is not a Firefox executable
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/real_path_here/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:524:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/real_path_here/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:601:13)
    at Executor.execute (/real_path_here/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:529:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  remoteStacktrace: ''
}

Node.js v18.15.0
```

I've tried setting the binary path since [these docs](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Usage.html#Running-Firefox-in-an-container-based-package) talk about an issue with snap/flatpak specifically on Ubuntu 22-04.

In the sample code I shared, because of the supposed snap/flatpak issue I downloaded a separate copy of firefox and try to specify that path on my system. The error message does not reflect that path, and instead gives a different browser path mentioning .cache. If I instead specify the path as /usr/bin/firefox, the error message will mirror that path, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it, but still don't entirely understand why it works.

I moved a copy of geckodriver to /usr/local/bin as someone suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40931903/1625040). It still didn't work but got a new error message about how I hadn't created a profile yet.

I then moved a copy of non-snap firefox also to /usr/local/bin, and specified that path for the binary:

```
  const firefoxOptions = new firefox.Options().setBinary('/usr/local/bin/firefox');

  // Create a new WebDriver instance with Firefox
  const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').setFirefoxOptions(firefoxOptions).build();
```

Then it works. Although it still lists a different path for the binary in the terminal. Also would love to get this working with my everyday version of firefox instead of this copy.

```
Driver path: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
Browser path: /home/greg/.cache/selenium/firefox/linux64/118.0.1/firefox
```